# Login without spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I want to make a simple login without using spring security.  Can anyone help me since all tutorial I find is based on spring security.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Spring Security, or any framework for that matter - the basic task of Authentication/Authorization can be done in 3 steps:

1. Write a Log In page, with a Form that accepts Username and Password (e.g. in a JSP)
2. Write a Controller method that reads the specified unique User's Password (Hashed!) from the Form and verifies it matches the (Hashed!) Password retrieved from a DB.  If they match, store a Token in the Session object.
3. Implement a Filter, that checks whenever the User tries to access a Secured page, that a valid Token object exists in the current Session

References:

Hashing:
https://www.stubbornjava.com/posts/hashing-passwords-in-java-with-bcrypt

Filters:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter

Here's one complete tutorial for the overall method:

https://medium.com/@kasunpdh/session-management-in-java-using-servlet-filters-and-cookies-7c536b40448f